# Using a numbered file descriptor from Java

Tags: java, file-io, freebsd

I need to access numbered file descriptors from Java -- other than 0, 1 or 2.

How can this be done?  I looked at the `FileDescriptor` class but did'nt find any way to initialize it with a given file descriptor number.

As a concrete example lets suppose Java gets called as a child process from another programing language.  File descriptors 3 and 4 are provided by the other language for input and output.

What I need in Java are `InputStream` and `OutputStream` objects connected to these file-descriptors, just like System.in, System.out and System.error are connected to file-desctiptors 0, 1 and 2.

I'm using Java 1.6 and this should run on Unix alike systems.

Comment: http://www.kfu.com/~nsayer/Java/jni-filedesc.html might help

Comment: Your working solution should be in an answer, not as part of the question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this can't be done using pure Java -- you'll probably have to use native code to bind a file descriptor to a FileDescriptor object or a FileInputStream or FileOutputStream object.

**EDIT**
If you're using Linux, *BSD or macOS, you can use the pseudo files /dev/fd/nnn to access file-descriptor nnn.

Comment: Yeah when learning from your answers that this isn't possible in Java itself (which I didn't dream of) I was looking into operating system support for it.  I'm running under FreeBSD and have /dev/fd/<nnn> for all open file descriptors.

Answer (score 13):

With a SUN JavaVM you can do:

```
FileDescriptor fd = new FileDescriptor();
sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaIOFileDescriptorAccess().set(fd,3);
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fd);
```

Comment: This is unsupported, not API and will break with Java 9.

Comment: Then, is there a similar approach for newer versions of Oracle HotSpot? What about in OpenJDK?

Answer (score 12):

I recently needed to do this for a Java child process running in a jail. This meant it did not have access to the /dev/fd filesystem.

@Bozho made a comment that reflection may or may not work to create a FileDescriptor object. It appears to work in a simple test I did, though. The following is source for TestFD.java:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class TestFD {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Constructor<FileDescriptor> ctor = FileDescriptor.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Integer.TYPE);
    ctor.setAccessible(true);
    FileDescriptor fd = ctor.newInstance(3);
    ctor.setAccessible(false);

    new FileOutputStream(fd).write("hi there\n".getBytes());
  }
}
```

To test this, I made a simple Bash script that compiles it, sets up fd3, and runs the java program:

```
#!/bin/bash

javac TestFD.java

exec 3>&1  # open fd3, redirect to stdout
java TestFD
exec 3>&-
```

Sure enough, fd3 is redirected to stdout, and outputs "hi there\n" on the terminal. Comment out the "exec 3>&1" line and the Java program fails as expected with a "Device not configured" IOException.

Reflection on the private FileDescriptor constructor seems to work fine in cases where access to /dev/fd is not possible, and is less clunky than trying to create a FileDescriptor using JNI, a suggestion that I have seen elsewhere.

Note: I tested this on a BSD system. It may or may not work on other systems.

Comment: This does not work on Windows, as the only constructor is the default one.

Comment: Works on Linux like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

To begin with:

> Applications should not create their own file descriptors

You can *try* using reflection to invoke the constructor `private FileDescriptor(int fd)`, by obtaining the constructor and calling `setAccessible(true)` on it. But that's a hack and I can't guarantee it will work (it's likely that it won't). Especially given the quote I started with.

Comment: My problem is that these file descriptors I get passed are a given by the runtime of the other language and other external constraints I have no influence in.  So the need for this is not by my choice.  I'll try your suggestion for the hack.

Comment: As you suspected ... it won't work.  I can only get public constructors via Class.getConstructor

Comment: @Peer Stritzinger - use `FileDescriptor.getDeclaredConstructor(..)`

Comment: It is a perfectly valid thing to open a raw file-descriptor. How else can a parent process pass a file.

Answer (score 0):

This content was previously added by the OP as a self-answer within the question, and is moved to a community-wiki answer in accordance with [What to do when OP answers his or her own question in an edit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74101/what-to-do-when-op-answers-his-her-own-question-in-an-edit).

---

**Tested working solution:**

The answer with the file descriptor special filesystem entries did point me to the following workable solution:

1. find out if and where your Unix alike system has a special filesystem that contains named entries for all file descriptors.

   - I'm using FreeBSD where [fdescfs(5)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fdescfs&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.1-RELEASE&format=html) is a filesystem that does just this.  Under Linux it would be procfs.
2. make sure this filesystem is mounted

   - FreeBSD: put `fdescfs /dev/fd fdescfs rw 0 0` in `/etc/fstab`

     or run `mount -t fdescfs null /dev/fd` on a shell prompt (probably with sudo)
3. Use new `FileInputStream("/dev/fd/3")` and `new FileOutputStream("/dev/fd/4")` to get the streams connected to the filedescriptors (the paths are for FreeBSD, replace with your operating systems paths)